# Is there an EE Version of Eclipse for Raspbian available?

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I would like to use my Raspi as a JavaApp-Server. I've Wildfly 11 installed. I'm using JDK 8.

But I also need Eclipse for EE. Installing the 32 bit version didn't work. By starting eclipse it said that the file is not correctly formatted. 
So is there an EE-Version available or do i need to take other measures to realize it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why install Eclipse on it? Can't you develop on a real computer and then deploy on the raspi?

Comment: Of course i could but I would like to do it on the raspi as well if possible.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen3a

Comment: I would not recommend that. Think of the raspi as your production server. You don't develop on that, only run things.

Comment: @j.seashell The problem is that there is no version for the ARM-Architectur. But Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Kayaman OK, i will do it on your way! Thank You!

Comment: It's not just my way :) it's a pretty standard way to operate.

Comment: That's true. I actually meant it that way. :D